# The ratio of two numbers is $7$ to $5$. The sum of the numbers is $24$. What are the numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The ratio of two numbers is $7$ to $5$. The sum of the numbers is $24$. What are the numbers

Comment: Hint: 24 is divisible by 12.

Comment: Is it 12 and 12?

Comment: You need to portion out $24$ into pieces in such a way that one portion has five lots and the other seven.

Comment: This is homework people; please don't post full answers, provide hints. I know a lot of you are well educated and well read in mathematics, it doesn't bode well for anyone else needing to learn for themselves how solve problems as these.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{7}{5} = \frac{x}{y}$$
$$x+y = 24.$$
Find the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

We are given the ratio of two numbers is $7$ to $5$.  Set $7x$ to be a first number and $5x$ to be a second number.  Write

$$7x + 5x = 24$$

Hence...

$$12x = 24 \rightarrow x = 2$$

So two numbers are $14$ and $10$.

Comment: Please, do not give away the answer to homework problems.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition the numbers have to be a multiple of $\frac75$ so we have to find the numbers $x$ and $y$ such that
$$\frac xy=\frac kk\cdot \frac 75,k\in \mathbb{N},x+y=24$$
Then if $k=2$ we have
$$\frac 22\cdot \frac 75=\frac{14}{10},x=14,y=10$$ and the sum of $x$ and $y$ is equal to 24